# ggplot only displaying some data in geom_line() timeseries

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using publicly available gas price data found [here](https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=pet&s=emm_epm0_pte_nus_dpg&f=m) to create a timeseries plot, but ggplot appears to be only displaying the data at each year point in January, and no other data. Can anyone help me determine why this is happening?

I'm using the following code:

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)
library(extrafont)
library(lubridate)
```

```
raw_data <- read.csv("H:/Projects/gas prices2.csv") %>%
  mutate(date2 = as.Date(dmy(date)))

frmt_data <- subset(raw_data, date2 >= as.Date("2012-01-01")) %>% 
  select(-date)

class(frmt_data$date2)
```

```
ggplot(frmt_data, aes(x = date2, y = price))+
  labs(x = "", y = "Dollars per Gallon ($)", caption = "SOURCE: U.S. Energy Information Administration") +
  annotate(geom = "segment", x = as.Date("2017-01-20"),
           xend = as.Date("2017-01-20"),
           y = 0, yend = 3.5, color = "#D5433E", size = 1) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = as.Date("2017-01-20"),
           y = 3.6, color = "black", size = 2.8, hjust = .5,
           label = expression("Jan 20: Trump\ntook Office")) + 
  annotate(geom = "segment", x = as.Date("2021-01-20"),
           xend = as.Date("2021-01-20"),
           y = 0, yend = 3.5, color = "#D5433E", size = 1) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = as.Date("2021-01-20"),
           y = 3.6, color = "black", size = 2.8, hjust = .5,
           label = expression("Jan 20: Biden\ntook Office")) +
  annotate(geom = "segment", x = as.Date("2020-03-11"),
           xend = as.Date("2020-03-11"),
           y = 0, yend = 3, color = "#D5433E", size = 1) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = as.Date("2020-03-01"),
           y = 3.1, color = "black", size = 2.8, hjust = .5,
           label = expression("COVID hits")) +
  geom_line(size = 1.2, lineend = "round", color = "#61D4D2") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format()) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b- %Y", date_breaks = "6 months") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 1.5), nrow = 1))+
  theme(
    text=element_text(family="Roboto Light"),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.key=element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 13, family = "Roboto Light"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
    plot.title = element_text(family = "Roboto", hjust = .5, vjust = 2.5),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0, 1.5, 0, 0), "cm"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size=.1, color="light grey"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 11, family = "Roboto Medium"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, size = 9),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13, margin = margin(t = 0, r = 6, b = 0, l = 0)),
    axis.line.x=element_line(),
    axis.line.y=element_line()
    )
```

[Resulting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyd09.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is exactly wrong with your code - I want to say that something happened with how the date values are being formatted. I was able to produce your figure after downloading the weekly data and converting it to a csv.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

raw_data <- read_csv("~/Downloads/EMM_EPM0_PTE_NUS_DPGw.csv", skip =2)
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   Date = col_character(),
#>   `Weekly U.S. All Grades All Formulations Retail Gasoline Prices  (Dollars per Gallon)` = col_double()
#> )

transmute(raw_data, Date = mdy(Date), 
          price = `Weekly U.S. All Grades All Formulations Retail Gasoline Prices  (Dollars per Gallon)`) %>%
  filter(Date >= ymd("2012-01-01")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, price)) +
  geom_line(color = "#61D4D2") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b- %Y", date_breaks = "6 months") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar_format(), expand = expansion(c(0,.1))) +
  annotate(geom = "segment", x = as.Date("2017-01-20"),
           xend = as.Date("2017-01-20"),
           y = 0, yend = 3.5, color = "#D5433E", size = 1) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = as.Date("2017-01-20"),
           y = 3.6, color = "black", size = 2.8, hjust = .5,
           label = expression("Jan 20: Trump\ntook Office")) + 
  annotate(geom = "segment", x = as.Date("2021-01-20"),
           xend = as.Date("2021-01-20"),
           y = 0, yend = 3.5, color = "#D5433E", size = 1) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = as.Date("2021-01-20"),
           y = 3.6, color = "black", size = 2.8, hjust = .5,
           label = expression("Jan 20: Biden\ntook Office")) +
  annotate(geom = "segment", x = as.Date("2020-03-11"),
           xend = as.Date("2020-03-11"),
           y = 0, yend = 3, color = "#D5433E", size = 1) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = as.Date("2020-03-01"),
           y = 3.1, color = "black", size = 2.8, hjust = .5,
           label = expression("COVID hits")) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.key=element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
    plot.title = element_text(family = "Roboto", hjust = .5, vjust = 2.5),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0, 1.5, 0, 0), "cm"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size=.1, color="light grey"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, size = 9),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13, margin = margin(t = 0, r = 6, b = 0, l = 0)),
    axis.line.x=element_line(),
    axis.line.y=element_line()
  )
#> Warning in is.na(x): is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type
#> 'expression'

#> Warning in is.na(x): is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type
#> 'expression'

#> Warning in is.na(x): is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type
#> 'expression'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, Justin! I think you are right, it probably had to do with how I saved the data. I saved a fresh copy and used your code and it now works. Thanks so much!